# Flask losing session data with two apps running in same browser

Tags: python, flask

I have two Flask apps, and launch (python myapp.py) each of them in a separate terminal.  One is at port 6600, the other at port 6800.  If I browse to either app (and not switch between the apps), everything works fine.

If, in the same browser I open both apps, if I switch between the apps (tabs in the browser), the next time I hit a redirect() (in either app), the session data is lost.  This happens in Chrome and Firefox.

If I use Chrome for one app, and Firefox for the other, I do NOT have this problem.

Each app is using a different app.secret_key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that both apps use the same session cookie in the same browser. You can fix it by renaming the `SESSION_COOKIE_NAME` which is `session` on all apps by default.

```
app.config.update(SESSION_COOKIE_NAME='some_new_name')
```

Comment: Thank you so much... I lost ~6 hours on this.